# DropDownList Items.Clear vs binding to a null datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have some code that in the PageLoad binds some default datasets to two DropDownLists (`ddlA` and `ddlB`). Both datasets have a `string.Empty` default selection.

When `ddlA` changes `ddlB` should get a new dataset based off `ddlA`'s selection.

I can get that to work just fine. The problem I face is when I select `ddlA`'s empty item `"--Select An Item from ddlA--"` I then try to bind a null datasource to `ddlB` and give it one default empty option `ddlB.DataSource = null; ddlB.DataBind(); ddlB.Items.Insert(0, [new list item])` and what I get is the initial dataset plus the new empty list item.

I checked and in the ddlA_SelectedIndexChanged I could do `ddlB.Items.Clear();`, but I am primarily wondering why binding a null datasource does not give me a DropDownList with no items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the logic of "ddlB is populated based off ddlA's selection" into it's own DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged fixed the issue. I think it's because a postback occurs so ddlB's datasource is already null and if I had selected the string.empty selection in ddlA then all it was doing at that point was adding a string.empty selection to a now empty datasource in ddlB